# Spring Amqp: Mix SimpleRoutingConnectionFactory with @RabbitListener

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I have an app that is gonna listen to multiple queues, which are declared on different vhost.  I used a SimpleRoutingConnectionFactory to store a connectionFactoryMap, and I hope to set up my listener with @RabbitListener.

According to Spring AMQP doc:

> Also starting with version 1.4, you can configure a routing connection
>   factory in a SimpleMessageListenerContainer. In that case, the list of
>   queue names is used as the lookup key. For example, if you configure
>   the container with setQueueNames("foo, bar"), the lookup key will be
>   "[foo,bar]" (no spaces).

I used `@RabbitListener(queues = "some-key")`. Unfortunately, spring complained "lookup key [null]". See below.

> 18:52:44.528  WARN --- [cTaskExecutor-1]
>   o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Consumer raised exception,
>   processing can restart if the connection factory supports it
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot determine target
>   ConnectionFactory for lookup key [null]   at
>   org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractRoutingConnectionFactory.determineTargetConnectionFactory(AbstractRoutingConnectionFactory.java:119)
>     at
>   org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractRoutingConnectionFactory.createConnection(AbstractRoutingConnectionFactory.java:97)
>     at
>   org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils$1.createConnection(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:90)
>     at
>   org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils.doGetTransactionalResourceHolder(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:140)
>     at
>   org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils.getTransactionalResourceHolder(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:76)
>     at
>   org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer.start(BlockingQueueConsumer.java:472)
>     at
>   org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1306)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

1. Did I do something wrong? If queues attribute is used as lookup key (for connection factory lookup), what am I supposed to use to specify which queue I'd like to listen to?
2. Ultimately, I hope to do programmatic/dynamic listener setup. If I use "Programmatic Endpoint Registration", am I supposed to drop "Annotation-driven listener endpoints"?  I love "Annotation-driven listener endpoints", because a listener could have multiple message handles with different incoming data type as argument, which is very clean and tidy. If I use Programmatic Endpoint Registration, I would have to parse the Message input variable, and call my a particular custom message handler based on the message type/content.

**EDIT:**
Hi Gary,
I modified your code #2 a little bit, so that it uses Jackson2JsonMessageConverter to serialize class objects (in RabbitTemplate bean), and use it to un-serialize them back to objects (in inboundAdapter). I also removed @RabbitListener because all listeners would be added at runtime in my case. Now the fooBean can receive integer, string and TestData message without any problem! The only issue left behind is that the program constantly report warning:

"[erContainer#0-1] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Consumer raised exception, processing can restart if the connection factory supports it

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot determine target ConnectionFactory for lookup key [null]". For the full stacktrace, please see the bottom.

Did I miss anything?

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class App2 implements CommandLineRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(App2.class, args);
    }

    @Autowired
    private IntegrationFlowContext flowContext;

    @Autowired
    private ConnectionFactory routingCf;

    @Autowired
    private RabbitTemplate template;

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        // dynamically add a listener for queue qux
        IntegrationFlow flow = IntegrationFlows.from(Amqp.inboundAdapter(this.routingCf, "qux").messageConverter(new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter()))
                .handle(fooBean())
                .get();
        this.flowContext.registration(flow).register();

        // now test it
        SimpleResourceHolder.bind(this.routingCf, "[qux]");
        this.template.convertAndSend("qux", 42);
        this.template.convertAndSend("qux", "fizbuz");
        this.template.convertAndSend("qux", new TestData(1, "test"));
        SimpleResourceHolder.unbind(this.routingCf);
    }

    @Bean
    RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate() {
        RabbitTemplate template = new RabbitTemplate(routingCf);
        template.setMessageConverter(new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter());
        return template;
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public ConnectionFactory routingCf() {
        SimpleRoutingConnectionFactory rcf = new SimpleRoutingConnectionFactory();
        Map<Object, ConnectionFactory> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("[foo,bar]", routedCf());
        map.put("[baz]", routedCf());
        map.put("[qux]", routedCf());
        rcf.setTargetConnectionFactories(map);
        return rcf;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory routedCf() {
        return new CachingConnectionFactory("127.0.0.1");
    }

    @Bean
    public Foo fooBean() {
        return new Foo();
    }

    public static class Foo {

        @ServiceActivator
        public void handleInteger(Integer in) {
            System.out.println("int: " + in);
        }

        @ServiceActivator
        public void handleString(String in) {
            System.out.println("str: " + in);
        }

        @ServiceActivator
        public void handleData(TestData data) {
            System.out.println("TestData: " + data);
        }
    }
}
```

Full stack trace:

```
2017-03-15 21:43:06.413  INFO 1003 --- [           main] hello.App2                               : Started App2 in 3.003 seconds (JVM running for 3.69)
2017-03-15 21:43:11.415  WARN 1003 --- [erContainer#0-1] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Consumer raised exception, processing can restart if the connection factory supports it

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot determine target ConnectionFactory for lookup key [null]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractRoutingConnectionFactory.determineTargetConnectionFactory(AbstractRoutingConnectionFactory.java:119) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractRoutingConnectionFactory.createConnection(AbstractRoutingConnectionFactory.java:97) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.doExecute(RabbitTemplate.java:1430) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:1411) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:1387) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin.initialize(RabbitAdmin.java:500) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin$11.onCreate(RabbitAdmin.java:419) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CompositeConnectionListener.onCreate(CompositeConnectionListener.java:33) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.createConnection(CachingConnectionFactory.java:571) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils$1.createConnection(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:90) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils.doGetTransactionalResourceHolder(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:140) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils.getTransactionalResourceHolder(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:76) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer.start(BlockingQueueConsumer.java:505) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1382) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_112]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please show your configuration - it works fine for me...

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class So42784471Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So42784471Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public ConnectionFactory routing() {
        SimpleRoutingConnectionFactory rcf = new SimpleRoutingConnectionFactory();
        Map<Object, ConnectionFactory> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("[foo,bar]", routedCf());
        map.put("[baz]", routedCf());
        rcf.setTargetConnectionFactories(map);
        return rcf;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory routedCf() {
        return new CachingConnectionFactory("10.0.0.3");
    }

    @RabbitListener(queues = { "foo" , "bar" })
    public void foobar(String in) {
        System.out.println(in);
    }

    @RabbitListener(queues = "baz")
    public void bazzer(String in) {
        System.out.println(in);
    }

}
```

Regarding your second question, you could build the endpoint manually but it's quite involved. It's probably easier to use a similar feature in a Spring Integration `@ServiceActivator`.

I will update this answer with details shortly.

**EDIT**

And here's the update using Spring Integration techniques to dynamically add a multi-method listener at runtime...

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class So42784471Application implements CommandLineRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So42784471Application.class, args);
    }

    @Autowired
    private IntegrationFlowContext flowContext;

    @Autowired
    private ConnectionFactory routingCf;

    @Autowired
    private RabbitTemplate template;

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        // dynamically add a listener for queue qux
        IntegrationFlow flow = IntegrationFlows.from(Amqp.inboundAdapter(this.routingCf, "qux"))
                .handle(fooBean())
                .get();
        this.flowContext.registration(flow).register();

        // now test it
        SimpleResourceHolder.bind(this.routingCf, "[qux]");
        this.template.convertAndSend("qux", 42);
        this.template.convertAndSend("qux", "fizbuz");
        SimpleResourceHolder.unbind(this.routingCf);
    }


    @Bean
    @Primary
    public ConnectionFactory routingCf() {
        SimpleRoutingConnectionFactory rcf = new SimpleRoutingConnectionFactory();
        Map<Object, ConnectionFactory> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("[foo,bar]", routedCf());
        map.put("[baz]", routedCf());
        map.put("[qux]", routedCf());
        rcf.setTargetConnectionFactories(map);
        return rcf;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory routedCf() {
        return new CachingConnectionFactory("10.0.0.3");
    }

    @RabbitListener(queues = { "foo" , "bar" })
    public void foobar(String in) {
        System.out.println(in);
    }

    @RabbitListener(queues = "baz")
    public void bazzer(String in) {
        System.out.println(in);
    }

    @Bean
    public Foo fooBean() {
        return new Foo();
    }

    public static class Foo {

        @ServiceActivator
        public void handleInteger(Integer in) {
            System.out.println("int: " + in);
        }

        @ServiceActivator
        public void handleString(String in) {
            System.out.println("str: " + in);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Hi Gray, thank you for your quick reply. I was hoping you to reply my question yesterday.  And you did!  I compiled and ran your code snippet #1, and got "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot determine target ConnectionFactory for lookup key [null]" as well. Any idea?  I'm using Spring boot 1.5.2, and created queues foo, bar & baz of course.

Comment: Hi Gary, code #2 looks promising. I modified a little bit. I updated my post. Please kindly take a look. There is a warning keeping annoying me. I guess I missed something important.

Comment: There is something strange going on - according to your stacktrace, the consumer is trying to connect via the `RoutingConnectionFactory` but according to [this code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/blob/1.7.x/spring-rabbit/src/main/java/org/springframework/amqp/rabbit/listener/AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java#L398) the target connection factory should have already been extracted. It looks like the container is being started before the queue names have been set up, which makes no sense to me. I am using Boot 1.5.2 too. Perhaps you can use a debugger to see what's happening?

Comment: Hi @gary-russell, I tried debugger but had no clue yet. I posted the full stack trace in my post. Do you have a little time to help me out by running my code on your computer, and see if you can reproduce the problem?

Comment: I just copied your code into my app and it works just fine (no errors). Did you set a breakpoint in `getConnectionFactory()`? Did the lookup not find a target factory? If you want to post your full project to github or somewhere, I can take a look at it.

Comment: Hi Gary, I did set a bp in that method. It did find a target factory.  Here is my project tgz file: <https://pan.baidu.com/s/1kUReixT>.  Hopefully you can download it successfully.  After that, please import it as a gradle project.

Comment: I see what's happening, and why it's not happening in my case; I have `spring.rabbitmq.dynamic=false` which disables the `RabbitAdmin` bean. Otherwise, we run the admin on the first thread that opens a connection to perform exchange/queue/binding declaration. You can work around it by setting that property, or by adding a default connection factory to the routing factory.

Comment: Thank you for your time and quick reply.  I was thinking of spring.rabbitmq.dynamic, which might be the reason why you didn't see the problem, when I was having shower 15 minutes ago.  It appears the error occurred during spring attempted to declare queue "qux". My goal is to listen to several queues (with the same name), which are created on different virtual hosts.  So I'm gonna to set up a group of connection factories for each virtual host.  (continue...)

Comment: Ok, I saw that you just opened an issue on jira.  Thank you Gary!

Comment: Because of AMQP-727, I suppose that I can only listen to queue NAME1 on vhost NAME1, rather than NAME2 on vhost NAME1.  No way to specify a queue name in integration flow.  Right?      IntegrationFlow flow = IntegrationFlows.from(Amqp.inboundAdapter(this.routingCf, "NAME1").......;

Comment: Interesting - we don't currently support the same queue name on different virtual hosts - I will add a qualifier to support that - I will update the JIRA issue.

Comment: I think the only work around for now is to configure the correct target connection factory directly into the container.

Comment: Got you. Thank you for your help!